# Xamarin.Forms ScrollView not scrolling anyway on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, windows-10-mobile

Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView not scrolling anyway no matter how I modified the code. Not even working with such simple code.

```cs
var text = "text";
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    text += "text"+i;
}
MainPage = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new ScrollView
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
        Content = new Label
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            Text = text,
        }
    }
};
```

Someone else is asking the same question, but no one gets answered. Is it a bug or what?

Comment: Is the content larger than the available space? The scroll viewer will only scroll if it needs to.

Comment: Sure. I appended the "text" for 5000 times.

Comment: what XF version are you using?

Comment: This is a bug! Report it here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED.**
Was using Xamarin Forms 2.0 and was no idea where to check about my Xamarin.Forms version.
I've tried to update Xamarin.Forms for Visual Studio but it was not installed to platform independents projects.
So I've solved it by doing following:
(with my Visual Studio Community 2015)
Go to **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**
Under "**Installed**" Tab Page,

Choose on "**Xamarin.Forms** by Xamarin Inc." , on the right side, I've noticed all the independent projects' Xamarin.Forms are still v.2.0, so thick all the Shared and Platform Independents Projects and select the target versions (v2.3) for Xamarin.Forms to Install it.

[image]

** Sorry I was not knowing any about these because none of the resources nor documentation pointed out about these settings.